# Count number of X+ occurrences of value in range

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project and was wondering if there might be a faster way of doing something that seems easy, but is fairly time consuming.

Pretend I have a 10 cell column filled with random integers from 1-10:

1. 1
2. 1
3. 1
4. 5
5. 5
6. 8
7. 8
8. 8
9. 9
10. 9

I want to get a count of x+ occurrence of this column. Func(1)=4 [since there are 4 unique values with at least 1 occurrence]; Func(2) =4; func(3)=2 [since only 2 unique values occur at least 3 times]

Right now I filter through each possible integer, then count occurrences. If occurrences >=x then count +=1. Then cycle through through each integer. It work, but on larger ranges of cells with greater range of integers, it is a bit slow. Given Excel's flexibility and the power of VBA, I'm wondering if anyone has an idea that is more efficient.

Comment: Shouldn't the 10th cell be 4 (instead of 3)? That way, `func(4)=1` (as stated in your question) would make sense.

Comment: @chillin I have updated the numbers and explanation - does that make more sense? I'm not looking for the count of a single value, I'm looking for the count of all values whose occurrence count is greater than or equal to x.

Comment: @Asger Thank you, I have updated the example to be a little more diverse. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach might be using a function like the below (but you'll need to add a reference by doing: `Open VB Editor > Click Tools > References > Scroll down to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" > Tick it > Click OK`)

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CountNumericOccurrences(ByVal someRange As Range, ByVal minimumOccurrenceCount As Long) As Long
    ' "someRange" can be a contiguous or non-contiguous range of cells
    ' "minimumOccurrenceCount" is how many occurrences must be present before that value is counted.
    ' This function will only count numbers (strings, blanks, etc are ignored).

    Dim uniqueCounts As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set uniqueCounts = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim contiguousArea As Range
    For Each contiguousArea In someRange.Areas
        If contiguousArea.Cells.Count > 1 Then ' Unlikely that range would contain any single-cell areas
            Dim inputToCheck As Variant
            inputToCheck = contiguousArea.Value

            Dim rowIndex As Long
            Dim columnIndex As Long
            Dim currentKey As String

            For rowIndex = LBound(inputToCheck, 1) To UBound(inputToCheck, 1)
                For columnIndex = LBound(inputToCheck, 2) To UBound(inputToCheck, 2)
                    If Application.IsNumber(inputToCheck(rowIndex, columnIndex)) Then ' IsNumeric returns True for vbEmpty, so isNumber is used instead.
                        currentKey = CStr(inputToCheck(rowIndex, columnIndex))
                        If Not uniqueCounts.Exists(currentKey) Then uniqueCounts.Add currentKey, 0 ' Default value
                        uniqueCounts(currentKey) = uniqueCounts(currentKey) + 1
                    End If
                Next columnIndex
            Next rowIndex

        ElseIf Application.IsNumber(contiguousArea) Then ' Handle single-cell edge case
            currentKey = CStr(contiguousArea) ' We repeat ourselves here. Could create a "default dictionary" class, but only 3 lines repeated.
            If Not uniqueCounts.Exists(currentKey) Then uniqueCounts.Add currentKey, 0 ' Default value
            uniqueCounts(currentKey) = uniqueCounts(currentKey) + 1
        End If
    Next contiguousArea

    For rowIndex = 0 To (uniqueCounts.Count - 1)
        If uniqueCounts.Items(rowIndex) >= minimumOccurrenceCount Then
            CountNumericOccurrences = CountNumericOccurrences + 1
        End If
    Next rowIndex
End Function
```

If you put it into a new module, you can call it from the worksheet as such:

[image: Usage]

I tested it with a range consisting of 200k cells, and it took ~4 seconds (quite slow). Maybe using a collection would be a better approach.

You could also just call it as part of a regular procedure e.g.:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SomeProcedure()
    Dim someValue As Long
    someValue = CountNumericOccurrences(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A200000"), 3)
    MsgBox someValue
End Sub
```